# convert CLOB to String in js

Tags: node.js, oracle, sequelize.js, clob

I want to convert clob to string in the node js app. I am using node js + express + sequelize and my DB is Oracle. I tried to use the sequelize findAll method but it not worked.
also, I use the cu8-sequelize-oracle module for connecting to Oracle Database.

I want to convert clob to string with pure javascript or use a module.

Comment: A comment from my colleague: You can define the type of the field as TEXT and it would return the CLOB column as a string by default. Are you using the sequelize v6.26.0? Can you share your code?

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I handled it in my code by converting chain data. I m using the sequelize v4.44.2. 4 years ago when I went to migrate from MySQL to Oracle I had to change in cu8-sequelize-oracle module to use sequelize after that I couldn't use "npm i" easily. so I never upgraded the sequelize version. I couldn't find out what version of oracle sequelize can support it.

Comment: We have tested with Oracle Database 19c and 21c.  You need Sequelize 6.25 or later. See https://medium.com/oracledevs/node-js-sequelize-with-oracle-database-its-official-dbbad242ff4c